# Cassandra load is high on one of the nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have an 8 node Cassandra cluster (Cassandra 2.0.8). When I ran the status using nodetool, I see the following. I am a newbie and wondering why the load on one of the nodes (that node is my initial seed node) is high compared to others?

I also noticed that when I try to push data into Cassandra Table (column family) using PIG, that one node is using very high CPU (95%+) while the others are not (20-30%)

```
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  15.55 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  36.89 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  3.77 GB    256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  1.04 GB    256     56.2%  ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  43.49 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  40.36 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  43.69 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
UN  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx  40.23 MB   256     6.2%   ------------------------------------  rack1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your replication factor?

Comment: What is the definition of the table which contains most of the load ?And how do you manage (or generate) the partition key ?

Comment: replication factor 1 and my table definition is as simple as CREATE TABLE emp (
  empID int,
  deptID int,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (empID, deptID)
);

Comment: I think I am using default partition which i believe is Murmur3Partitioner

Comment: I'm not posting answer because I'm not sure if it will be enough, change the replication factor, if it remains 1 there will be only one copy of each record and it will be stored on a single node

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are pushing data through PIG. If so are you using the Hadoop support of Cassandra?

If yes, it is likely that your splits are causing this.